# Using the same regex for multiple specific columns in R

Tags: r, regex

I have the data as below

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(obs = 1:4, text0 = c("nothing to do with this column even it contains keywords", 
"FIFA text", "AFC text", "UEFA text"), text1 = c("here is some FIFA text", 
"this row dont have", "some UEFA text", "nothing"), text2 = c("nothing here", 
"I see AFC text", "Some samples", "End of text")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

obs                                                    text0                  text1          text2
1   1 nothing to do with this column even it contains keywords here is some FIFA text   nothing here
2   2                                                FIFA text     this row dont have I see AFC text
3   3                                                 AFC text         some UEFA text   Some samples
4   4                                                UEFA text                nothing    End of text
```

**Expected Output**:

```
  obs                                                    text0                  text1          text2
1   1 nothing to do with this column even it contains keywords here is some FIFA text   nothing here
2   2                                                FIFA text     this row dont have I see AFC text
3   3                                                 AFC text         some UEFA text   Some samples
```

**Question**: I have several columns contains some keywords (`FIFA, UEFA, AFC`) I am looking for. I want to filter these keywords on specific columns (in this case: `text1`, and `text2` only). Any those keywords founded in `text1` and `text2` should be filtered as the expected output. We have nothing to do with `text0`. I am wondering if there is any regex to get this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `filter_at`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
patvec <- c("FIFA", "UEFA", "AFC")
# // create a single pattern string by collapsing the vector with `|`
# // specify the word boundary (\\b) so as not to have any mismatches
pat <- str_c("\\b(", str_c(patvec, collapse="|"), ")\\b")
df %>%
    filter_at(vars(c('text1', 'text2')),
             any_vars(str_detect(., pat)))
```

---

With `across`, currently does the `all_vars` matching instead of `any_vars`.  An option is `rowwise` with `c_across`

```
df %>% 
   rowwise %>%
   filter(any(str_detect(c_across(c(text1, text2)), pat))) %>% 
   ungroup
```

Comment: I am trying to using `across()`, but fails to get the result.

Comment: @ThoVu you may need `c_across`, currently `across` use `all_vars`

Comment: that is exactly what I am working on. Thanks for your great explanation and quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try (`base R`):

```
#Keys
keys <- c('FIFA', 'UEFA', 'AFC')
keys <- paste0(keys,collapse = '|')
#Filter
df[grepl(pattern = keys,x = df$text1) | grepl(pattern = keys,x = df$text2),]
```

Output:

```
  obs                                                    text0                  text1          text2
1   1 nothing to do with this column even it contains keywords here is some FIFA text   nothing here
2   2                                                FIFA text     this row dont have I see AFC text
3   3                                                 AFC text         some UEFA text   Some samples
```

Comment: it is very helpful to me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option:

```
pat <- sprintf("\\b(%s)\\b",paste(patvec, collapse = "|"))
subset(df, grepl(pat, do.call(paste, df[c("text1","text2")])))
  obs                                                    text0                  text1          text2
1   1 nothing to do with this column even it contains keywords here is some FIFA text   nothing here
2   2                                                FIFA text     this row dont have I see AFC text
3   3                                                 AFC text         some UEFA text   Some samples
```